# Можно ли определить высоту в Dpi или размер в разметке относительно размеров экрана

Tags: android, android-xml

Возможно заголовок вопроса не корректный. Я запутался. У меня высота SurfaceView задается в разметке. Мне нужно задавать её равной 0.7 от размера экрана текущего устройства. Неужели нельзя в разметке получить размер текущего устройства в пикселях?

Comment: Программирование под андроид на java-  дело православное, но бессмысленное. Ты и так можешь юзать java код из Qt, почему бы не писать программу на Qml?

Comment: Прям заинтриговали. Первый раз слышу про Qml. Забил в гугл, понял что это замена древнему xml. Но разве я могу в андроид студио использовать его? как вообще использовать Qml ,чтобы именно им делать разметку интерфейса андроид приложений?

Comment: А зачем эта Android Studio? Когда пишешь на ней набор виджетов даёт возможность написать разве что "Hello world". Нет диаграмм для бизнес приложений. Пишите в Qt Creator. qt.io, там есть версия для андроида.

Comment: Вот пример, вызывающий код в java

Comment: github.com /tripolskypetr/qmlcontactlist

Comment: github.com /tripolskypetr/qmlchooseimage

Comment: Так разве в Qt Creator можно писать на java ? я не программист , я только Qbasic в школе учил, только вот синтаксис java освоил . Для меня из языка в язык прыгать это не как через калитку перелезть. Ладно, это , а как быть с играми с использованием openGl, есть ли мощные движки типо libgdx или andEngine на Qt. Или я не совсем понимаю, что такое Qml?

Comment: дайте пожалуйста немного для не программиста(почти) понятный ответ ,что такое qml и что теперь все крутые прогеры на нем под андроид пишут ? и игры ?  с какой целью вообще создали Qt

Comment: Послушайте добрый совет и не пишите ничего для Android ни на Qt ни на qml ни в Qt Creator

Comment: Там есть эта тема. И java код вызвать на android можно, видно в моих примерах. Поищите QmlCreator в Google Play, там найдете джойстик для игр и кучу других примеров

Comment: pavlofff, хоть немного прокомментируйте ваш выбор?

Comment: Какой еще выбор.. выбор не использовать Qt в проектах Android? если у вас склонности к мазохизму, то можете попробовать и Qt на Android, в противном случае не стоит с этим связываться. На Qt под Android пишут 1.5 человека и то больше из упрямства, наверное ..

Comment: Насчет вашего вопроса. У google есть [библиотека поддержки](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/percent-part-1/) *support:persent*, в которой есть класс [`PercentFrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) - помещаете в него ваш `SurfaceView` и указываете маржины в 15%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не мучайтесь и используйте специальный лейаут для таких случаев - называется `PercentRelativeLayout`

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <SurfaceView
         app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="70%"
     >
     </SurfaceView>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

[документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

ЗЫ: входит в состав [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html)

Comment: в данном конкретном случае (один вложенный элемент) более уместен и гораздо легче будет класс из той же бибилотеки `PercentFrameLayout`

Comment: я уже пользовался этой библиотекой..что то сразу не подумал. Немного отдохну и поэксперементирую, спасибо

Comment: раз ставятся проценты , то значит есть способ в разметке получить текущий размер экрана в пикселях, иногда может это быть проще ,чтобы не подключать библиотеку. Знаете ли вы как получить размер экрана в разметке?

Comment: Конечно знаем. Оформите вопрос и получите ответ

Comment: Прошу  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615068

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать с помощью веса. Поместить нужную вьюху меж других вьюх и раздать им соответствующие веса

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    >
    <Space
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="15"
       android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <SurfaceView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="70"
       android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <Space
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="15"
       android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Создай корневой элемент, чтобы он занимал всё пространство окна. В него уже суй SurfaceView. Из конструктора задавай ему 70% от корневого элемента

Comment: очень неудобно..ведь так просто получить в xml размер экрана в пикселях и от него дальше плясать..но увы похоже нельзя. Выше мне подсказали про Qml, надеюсь этот чудо-зверь подойдет. Ваш предложенный костыль может и поможет