# Как получить размер дисплея в xml разметке

Tags: java, android, разметка

Библиотека com.android.support:percent:25.0.1 позволяет работать с процентами. Значит можно получить и размер дисплея в пикселях в xml. Как ?

Comment: Если не секрет, то что вы хотите сделать дальше и какую задачу решить? Как размер дисплея в процентах в xml поможет Вам решить эту задачу?

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли. Если с помощью этой библиотеки в xml можно задать размер Вьюв 30% от размера дисплея, значит библиотека в xml может получить размер дисплея в пикселях. Сейчас уточню чуть вопрос.

Comment: Из одного другое не следует. Но даже если так: что Вы дальше сможете сделать с этими данными в xml ?  Не проще ли решить Вашу задачу в Java-коде, а не xml?

Comment: Опишите в вопросе то, чего Вы хотите добиться. Вполне возможно, что Ваша задача может иметь решение, которое ускользнуло от Вас.

Comment: В целом работать с пикселями в андроиде крайне не рекомендуется, поэтому любое решение основанное на работе с пикселями(хоть в xml, хоть в активити) ,будет оставлять желать лучшего.

Comment: мне кажется что Вам для начала лучше изучить руководства Google по этому поводу. В частности для поддержки разных экранов. https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: смысл в том, чтобы использовать различные, xml в зависимости от различных разрешений экрана (xxxhdpi, xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi)

Comment: также смотрите по теме: http://www.fandroid.info/podderzhka-raznyh-razreshenij-ekrana-v-android-prilozheniyah/

Comment: Нельзя получиь размер дисплея в пикселях в xml, потому что это не требуется для верстки. Вы можете получить размер экрана программно, но в большинстве случаев и это не требуется для решения задачи. Зачем вам этот размер?

Comment: У меня код реализован относительно пикселей.  Шарик дойдя до 0.7*высота_экрана меняет направление. Хочу например высоту поля view 0.7*высота_экрана. Пропорции соблюдаются таким образом на всех экранах в точности до пикселей.

Answer (score 4):

Коллега,

Вы похоже, не совсем точно представляете как работает оконная система Android'а

XML это ваши пожелания как бы вы хотели, чтобы выглядел экран. Далее начинается развертка ваших хотелок на физическом экране. Развертка выполняется в 2 этапа:

1. Делается замер размеров с учетом пожеланий указанных в XML и ограничений заданных родителем. Это часть выполняется методом `View.measure()`, метод вызывает `onMeasure()`, который может быть перехвачен разработчиком.
2. Далее присваиваются актуальные размеры вычисленные в ходе `measure/onMeasure()` - это производится методом `View.layout()`, в ходе присвоения размеров вызывается `onLayout()`, который также может быть перехвачен.

Замер размеров и присвоение происходит **динамически** то есть runtime, соответственно, отсутствует способ задать статические размеры в XML.

Динамически найти размеры экрана устройства не представляет никакой сложности, код типа:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x; //ширина экрана в пикселях
int height = size.y; //высота экрана в пикселях
```

Эти размеры по идее вы должны использовать в `onMeasure()/onLayout()`, для того чтобы придать желаемый размер вашему кастомному `View`

Погуглите на тему *custom+view+android*

Answer (score 1):

Работа с px не рекомендуется, это где такое сказано? Любые динамические манипуляции в коде будут проходить в px, поэтому зачастую перед более большим проектом пишется утилита, которая генерирует px -> dp, для удобной работы, но по факту, 'почти' все динамические измерения в px. 
Что касается вопроса, библиотека и получения размеров это две разные вещи, библиотека для того и нужна чтоб, не получать эти размеры, а смело ставить проценты, а она в коробке сама считает все остальное. Ну а если вы уже вытащили размеры вашего парента, не надо много ума, чтоб разделить этот размер на размер вашего элемента и получить те же самые проценты, или поставить процент от вашего размера, чтоб задать нужный размер уже в пикселях, ну или если вернутся в начало можно использовать свою утиль, чтоб удобно ставить в % а на выходе иметь dp.

*PS Bonus*: В такой ситуации рекомендую использовать FrameLayout, он хорошо подойдет именно для таких манипуляций, а для списков может дать значительный прирост производительности, парой очень большой. Такие примеры можно увидеть в глобальных OpenSource, в топовых мессенджерах и файлменеджерах...